# Community reviewed a suggested edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, community-user

Today I was reviewing suggested edits, and wanted to see what other people thought of that suggest as well. So I went back to that page, and I saw something odd. I would usually see many people Approving/Rejecting the edit, or maybe just me. However, this time, I saw that **Community** reviewed the edit. What does that mean?

[image]